# FailedCreatePodSandBox on GCP Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

> Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  6s (x6 over 74s)  kubelet, gke-xxxx-default-pool-71axxxx-dkbr  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 1xx.2xx.1xx.2xx:53: server misbehaving

This is the status of my pod when I run: `kubectl describe pod <podname>`
and also the pod says its in the container creating state.

Comment: Also i don't find any solution for this problem anywhere on the web.

Comment: Sounds like a temporary problem on the DNS server, I bet it'll work now if you try.

Comment: this error describe that you can not pull the image from the container registry, are you using istio and the cluster is provate? need more details and past all your config file .